# Which versions of Apache are currently supported?

Tags: apache-2.4

PHP includes this graphic which shows which versions are supported:

[image]
(captured from 2016-01-08)
https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php

---

Is there are similar graphic or information available for Apache?

Comment: I believe it's much more useful to consider the support time frame of your distribution of choice. They are the one that need to make sure the Apache they ship is secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to find this information for the specific distribution you are using as their support time frames are different from the Apache project.

For example, CentOS 6.7 has httpd 2.2 with php 5.3 (unsupported by php community) which will be supported till 2020. Similarly CentOS 7 has httpd 2.4 with php 5.6 (supported by php community until 2019) which will be supported till 2024.

Debian/Ubuntu distros have different support arrangements and so on.